# BOOST ASIO - asynchronous sockets

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use BOOST ASIO library asynchronous sockets.
My platform is Linux.
My client sends data, which I am able to read at server side.
For sending data second time, client has to connect again.
Is there a way I can use asynchronous sockets and keep the connection alive till explicit disconnection.

Details of my code:-

Server side I have used async_accept() which looks like this

```
_acceptor.async_accept(_connection->socket(),
    boost::bind(&Server::handleAccept,
                     this,
                     boost::asio::placeholders::error));

handleAccept() looks like this
{
    _connection->start();
    _connection.reset(new Connection(_ioService));
    _acceptor.async_accept(_connection->socket(),
                           boost::bind(&Server::handleAccept,
                           this,
                           boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

start() function looks like this:-
  _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer),
                          _strand.wrap(
                            boost::bind(
                              &Handler::handleRead,
                              shared_from_this(),
                              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                              )
                          )
```

In my `handleRead()` function, I dump the data on screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well in `Handler::handleRead()` you got to schedule the `async_read_some()` again